# Python Authentication: PAM or LDAP bind() vs. LDAP {SSHA} check?

Tags: ldap, pam

I'm writing a fairly simple internal application (currently prototyped in [Bottle](http://www.bottlepy.org/)) which will send notification for incidents and change management events to an internal mailing list while forcing these notices to conform to a couple of standard templates (and ensuring, through the [Python Jira API](https://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) that the required issue references exist and are in the appropriate state).

Naturally we require that users authenticate to my application before I send messages which will be attributed to them.  We use LDAP and all password hashes are stored in {SSHA} format.

I've found at least three different ways to perform the authentication:

- bind to LDAP with a service account with sufficient LDAP ACIs to fetch password hashes (same as our */etc/sssd/sssd.conf* systems level authentication), use that to find the **dn** and extract the 'userPassword' attribute; then validate that against the proposed password using ***hashlib***
- bind to LDAP with a service account with limited search privileges, use that to find the user's **dn** and then attempt to bind to LDAP using that **dn** and the users proposed password
- Use the *authenticate()* functions from either the [simplepam](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplepam/0.1.5) (pure Python/[ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) wrapper) or [python-pam](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-pam/1.8.2) modules

Here's code which seems to correctly implement the first of these:

```
#!python
import hashlib
import ConfigParser, os
from base64 import encodestring as encode
from base64 import decodestring as decode

import ldap

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read(os.path.expanduser('~/.creds.ini'))
uid = config.get('LDAP', 'uid')
pwd = config.get('LDAP', 'pwd')
svr = config.get('LDAP', 'svr')
bdn = config.get('LDAP', 'bdn')

ld = ldap.initialize(svr)
ld.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
ld.simple_bind_s(uid, pwd)

def chk(prop, pw):
    pw=decode(pw[6:])         # Base64 decode after stripping off {SSHA}
    digest = pw[:20]          # Split digest/hash of PW from salt
    salt = pw[20:]            # Extract salt
    chk = hashlib.sha1(prop)  # Hash the string presented
    chk.update(salt)          # Salt to taste:
    return chk.digest() == digest

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from getpass import getpass
    max_attempts = 3

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print 'Must supply username against which to authenticate'
        sys.exit(127)
    name = sys.argv[1]

    user_dn = ld.search_s(bdn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, '(uid=%s)' % name)
    if len(user_dn) < 1:
        print 'No DN found for %s' % name
        sys.exit(126)
    pw = user_dn[0][1].get('userPassword', [''])[0]

    exit_value = 1
    attempts = 0
    while attempts < max_attempts:
        prop = getpass('Password: ')
        if chk(prop, pw):
            print 'Authentication successful'
            exit_value = 0
            break
        else:
            print 'Authentication failed'
        attempts += 1
    else:
        print 'Maximum retries exceeded'
    sys.exit(exit_value)
```

This seems to work (assuming we have the appropriate values in our `.creds.ini`).

Here's a bit of code implementing the second option:

```
#!python
# ...
### Same ConfigParser and LDAP initialization as before
# ...

def chk(prop, dn):
    chk = ldap.initialize(svr)
    chk.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
    try:
        chk.simple_bind_s(dn, prop)
    except ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS:
        return False
    chk.unbind()
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from getpass import getpass
    max_attempts = 3


    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print 'Must supply username against which to authenticate'
        sys.exit(127)
    name = sys.argv[1]

    user_dn = ld.search_s(bdn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, '(uid=%s)' % name)
    if len(user_dn) < 1:
        print 'No distinguished name (DN) found for %s' % name
        sys.exit(126)

    dn = user_dn[0][0]

    exit_value = 1
    attempts = 0
    while attempts < max_attempts:
        prop = getpass('Password: ')
        if chk(prop, dn):
            print 'Authentication successful'
            exit_value = 0
            break
        else:
            print 'Authentication failed'
        attempts += 1
    else:
        print 'Maximum retries exceeded'
    sys.exit(exit_value)
```

Not shown here but I also tested that I can continue to use the `ld` LDAP connection independently of the transient `chk` LDAP object.  So my long-running web service can keep re-using the one connection.

The last options are almost identical regardless of which of the two PAM modules I use.  Here's an example using **python-pam**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pam

pam_conn = pam.pam()

def chk(prop, name):
    return pam_conn.authenticate(name, prop)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from getpass import getpass
    max_attempts = 3


    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print 'Must supply username against which to authenticate'
        sys.exit(127)
    name = sys.argv[1]

    exit_value = 1
    attempts = 0
    while attempts < max_attempts:
        prop = getpass('Password: ')
        if chk(prop, name):
            print 'Authentication successful'
            exit_value = 0
            break
        else:
            print 'Authentication failed'
        attempts += 1
    else:
        print 'Maximum retries exceeded'
    sys.exit(exit_value)
```

My question is: which of these should I use.  Are any of them particularly less secure than the others?  Is there any consensus on "best practices" for this?

Comment: In the end: Which way did you implemented?

Comment: The second method (bind to LDAP with the userDN), as recommended by @jwilleke below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely use a bind as the userDN and password presented by the user.

"bind to LDAP with a service account with limited search privileges, use that to find the user's dn and then attempt to bind to LDAP using that dn and the users proposed password"

Sorry, I do not know how the "Authenticate() functions" behave.

Not binding as the  userDN, may bypass the builtin server functions that apply to password policy or account restrictions and intruder detection.

-jim